# The galois group of the polynomial $x^9+x^3+1$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

What is the galois group of  the polynomial $x^9+x^3+1$?  Moreover give the bijection between subgroups and intermediate fields.

#### Progress

I think the order of the group is 108. But, there are many groups of order 108.

Comment: Herstein asks for the order of the group...which I think is 108.

Comment: But, there are many groups of order 108...

Comment: the hint does not help me...maybe you could develop your thoughts a bit more....?

Comment: @mark The hint was wrong anyway

Comment: how can the group order be 108? You can start with the roots of $y^3+y+1$, which have degree at most 6, then cube roots of that is another $3$ and a $3^{rd}$ root of unity at degree at most $2$ should bound the degree at 36.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Are you sure that if you adjoin the cube roots of one of the zeros of $y^3+y+1$ you get the cube roots of the other zeros free of charge?

Comment: Oh rats, the complex zeroes are more messed up, duh. Thanks @Jyrki.

Comment: Yeah. The product of the roots of $y^3+y+1$ is $-1$, so adjoining the cubic roots of two of them does give those of the the third. By your calculation we then get an upper bound of 108.

Answer (score 0):

The galois group,
G, is a semidirect product of the unique non-abelian group, H, of order 27 and exponent 3 with the Klein 4-group, V.